# Can I use QLThumbnailImageCreate on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

The QuickLook/QLThumbnailImage.h cannot be found, even I added Quicklook.framework.
If it can be used Only on cocoa, what's the similar api on iOS to get a file's thumbnail, not icon?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, thumbnails are a DIY affair.

Fortunately though, there are a LOT of examples/tutorials on how to do it.

[Start at the top and work your way down.](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=uiimage%20thumnail&hl=en)

Comment: Well, I found the examples are all resize from big image to small thumbnail. But how about from a file,say pdf, doc,etc... to thumbnail?

Comment: Some of those methods involve doing it from a UIWebView, which is what you would probably use for a pdf, doc, etc.

Comment: I'm filing a bug report with Apple to have this feature added (`QLThumbnailImageCreate`). I encourage you to do the same, as Apple judges which features they should add in based on demand. The problem with using a `UIWebView` to create thumbnails (such as for Office and iWork documents) is that it's too involved and memory intensive considering what you're getting out of it (a small image of the first page of the document), and `UIWebView` renders its pages on the main thread, so your app could potentially freeze if you need to create thumbnails for multiple files.